# How to use Dependency Injection in azure data factory custom activity

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, azure-data-factory

I have an activity:

```cs
public class TriggerActivity : CrossAppDomainDotNetActivity<TriggerContext>
{
    //...

    protected override TriggerContext PreExecute(IEnumerable<LinkedService> linkedServices, IEnumerable<Dataset> datasets, Activity activity, IActivityLogger logger)
    {
        //...
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, string> Execute(TriggerContext context, IActivityLogger logger)
    {
        //...
    }
```

and I am wondering what initial setup I should use to be able to use dependency injection for that activity class. Is it even possible?

Does that activity require parameterless constructor or it is possible to use some kind of activator to be able to inject dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no native DI support on the activity class as ADF job launcher always uses parameter-less constructor.

You can definitely plug your own DI-supported class types into the Execute method though.